# llenar array asociativo dinámicamente

Tags: php, api

Estoy tratando de integrar Viafirma a mi proyecto, es una API para firmar documentos online. Pero estoy teniendo bastantes problemas para crear la petición de añadir documentos.

Tengo este Array:

```
$json = [
            "groupCode" => $groupCode,
            "title" => "Solicitud de Firma",
            "description" => "Solicitud de Firma - Descripción",
            "customization" => [
                "requestMailSubject" => "Mi Email Subject",
                "requestMailBody" => "Mi Email Body",
                "requestSmsBody" => "SMS Body"
            ],
            "recipients" => [
                [
                    "key" => "firmante01",
                    "presential" => true
                ]
            ],
            /*"policies"  => [
                "attachments" => [], // it´s filled below
            ],*/         
            "messages" => [
                [
                    "document" => [
                        "templateType" => "base64",
                        "templateCode" => $templateCode, //"564FDSA4765",
                        "templateReference" => $pdfInBase64,
                        "autoFinalize" => true,
                        "formRequired" => true,
                        //"items" => $items,
                    ],
                    "metadataList" => $metaDataList,
                    "callbackURL" => "http://www.crm.local:8081/viafirma/callback", // "https://intranet.grupodeluxe.com/viafirma/callback",
                    "callbackAuthorization" => "Basic " . "viafirmaapi" . ":" . "f1rm4v1420$",
                    "callbackMails" => "23850juridico@grupodeluxe.com",
                    "callbackMailFilename" => "PRECONTRATO_" . $precontract["insert_id"]["precontract_id"] . ".pdf"
                ],
            ],
        ];
```

Necesito añadir en este array:

```
"policies"  => [
   "attachments" => [], // it´s filled below
 ],
```

Mis documentos con la siguiente estructura:

```
[type] => PDF
[helpText] => Documento adjunto
[fileReference] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1cGxvYWRFeHBpcmVzIjoiMTY5Njg4NDI2OTY3OCIsInVwbG9hZENvZGUiOiIxNjk2ODg0MjY5Njc4X2Q5M2JhZmE5LWFlNmUtNDQ1Ny04YmI4LTFmYjk0NDMyNzYzMy5wZGYifQ.It0CB0K6ffp9nT_QdlB1YlhkOyWyNY4U5RzLzDjLe9g
[fileName] => cartilla_banco.pdf
[readOnly] => 1
```

Para ello, estoy tratando de hacerlo así:

```
$json["messages"]["policies"]["attachments"][] = $document;
```

la variable `$document` es un array que contiene todos los documentos, obtenidos en una query y haciendo un for:

```
$precontractDocument = PrecontractAttachment::where('precontract_id', $precontract["insert_id"]["precontract_id"])->get();
        $attachments = [];
        $document = [];
        $tokens = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($precontractDocument); $i++) {
            array_push($tokens, $this->getSecurityTokensViaFirma());
            $attachments["type"] = "PDF_IMAGE";
            $attachments["processType"] = "OCR";
            $attachments["helpText"] = "Documento adjunto";
            $attachments["fileReference"] = $tokens[$i];
            $attachments["fileName"] = $precontractDocument[$i]["filename_result"];
            $attachments["readOnly"] = true;
            $attachments["signature"]["type"] = "SERVER";
            array_push($document, $attachments);
            //$json["policies"]["attachments"] = $document;
            $this->uploadDocumentViafirma($document, $tokens, $precontract["insert_id"]["precontract_id"]);
        }
```

El problema que estoy teniendo es que siempre me está devolviendo la petición al servidor un 400, es un error en la creación de la petición (los datos que se le envían). Y me están fallando los datos de los documentos.

Necesito que tenga esta estructura:

```
"policies"  => [
       "attachments" => [], // it´s filled below
     ],
```

pero estoy obteniendo esta:

```
[policies] => Array
                (
                    [attachments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [type] => PDF_IMAGE
                                            [processType] => OCR
                                            [helpText] => Documento adjunto
                                            [fileReference] => eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1cGxvYWRFeHBpcmVzIjoiMTY5NjkzNDY3MTMzOCIsInVwbG9hZENvZGUiOiIxNjk2OTM0NjcxMzM4X2Y4NDdmNjYxLWMzYjgtNDNhNC04ZjMzLWFhODAwNDA4MDc4NS5wZGYifQ.guwWx8IWVDqiB58o6oPXSCY3tpZ-JJ-tGfr1IFdNvng
                                            [fileName] => dni_trasero
                                            [readOnly] => 1
                                            [signature] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] => SERVER
                                                )

                                        )
```

También he probado a añadir así la información: `$json["messages"]["policies"]["attachments"] = $document;` y así si parece que es la estructura que necesito, pero sigo recibiendo un 400 por parte del API (un error).

Según el API, tengo que mandar la información de esta manera:

```
"policies" : [ {
"attachments" : [ {
                "type" : "IMAGE",
                "helpText" : "Adjunto test: IMAGE",
                "signature": {
                    "type" : "SERVER"
                }
            } ],
            "signatures" : [ {
                "type" : "SERVER"
            } ]
        } ]
```

Alguien me puede ayudar a formar este array¿?

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Hola. Lo primero es que [el ejemplo de estructura que dices que pide la API no valida](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/vEVSnyMa). Por favor, pon en la pregunta un ejemplo de estructura válido. Para comprobar la validación puedes copiar / pegar la cadena en un validador en línea. En segundo lugar, convierte a JSON lo que estás obteniendo y también agrégalo a la pregunta. Así será más fácil para ti y para nosotros ver dónde está el error.

Comment: al parecer estas enviando un array de php y la API lo que hace es recibir un JSON, por lo que debes hacer es convertir a Json el array, debes hacer que el array sea correcto en su formato.